# Spring Boot with non-embedded Tomcat: loader constraint violation error

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have an error when trying to display a JSP with Spring Boot. Here is my configuration:

- Spring source STS (last version)
- Spring Boot 1.1.8 (last release to date)
- Java 1.7
- Tomcat 8.0.14 (I'm not using the embedded tomcat, so I launch manually with the spring boot application added)

My JSP file is barebones:

```
TEST
```

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.edhec</groupId>
<artifactId>stdapps</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>stdapps</name>
<description>Project stdapps</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- CAS Client -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jasig.cas.client</groupId>
       <artifactId>cas-client-core</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.3</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
       <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>com.edhec.stdapps.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <tomcat.version>8.0.14</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the error I get :

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/views/agreement2/index_jsp, and the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) for resolved class, org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class objects for the type .getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager; used in the signature
```

I think it has a relation with el or jsp-api version, I try to add manually in the pom.xml but got same error or sometimes 'noClassDefFoundError on my compiled jsp'

Does someone see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 18):

Due to your dependency on `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-websocket` and their transitive dependencies, you're packaging Tomcat inside your war file. This is leading to there being two different versions of Tomcat's classes available and is caused the constraint violation. You need to mark the Tomcat dependencies as provided so that they don't get packaged in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Add the following dependencies to your pom:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

It's preferable to mark the dependencies as provided, rather than excluding them altogether, as it allows your war file to be deployed to Tomcat or executed with `java -jar`. This works because the provided dependencies are packaged in `WEB-INF/lib-provided` where they'll be ignored by a standalone Servlet container but be available when you're using the embedded container.

Comment: Thanks Andy for your quick response, but I already add this in the pom but I still get the error. (I have update the original post with my current pom.xml)

Comment: Double-check what's in your war file. There may be something else that's in WEB-INF/lib but shouldn't be. Perhaps you could post the output from `unzip -l your-app.war`

Comment: Hi Andy, I've just update the original post with the jar list. I'm not using a war for now, I'm using embedded server feature in STS

Comment: I just manually delete tomcat-embed-core-8.0.14.jar in the lib dir. The error is gone ! How can I tell spring boot to not include this jar ? I see in the dependency hierarchy that in spring-boot-starter-tomcat (declared provided) the dependency tomcat-embed-core is set to 'compile', the other dependecies are set to 'provided'.

Comment: I also see that spring-boot-starter-websocket has tomcat-embed-core as 'compile' in it's dependencies

Comment: I solve the problem by excluding tomcat-embed-core from spring-boot-starter-tomcat and spring-boot-starter-websocket and adding just tomcat-embed-core with scope provided ... but It's not very clean I think.

Comment: Aah, I'd missed the websocket dependency. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I was experiencing a similar problem as OP but I only had dependencies for spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-test, and spring-web. I had removed any dependency for Tomcat. Strangely the app worked fine on some Tomcat environments but not for others. I looked at the pom's Dependency Hierarchy in Eclipse/STS and noticed some Tomcat jars were still being included. After finding this answer, I added the above dependencies back with the provided scope and everything works as expected. The Dependency Hierarchy now reflects that the Tomcat jars are provided. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In gradle I added this line to dependencies:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
   ...
}
```